# Interview: How many photographs are taken in a day

Tags: puzzle

I was recently asked this question in interview **"How many photographs are taken in a day around the world"**. I know its vague, but i tried asking interviewer lot of questions to get more information from him, but in the end yeah interviewer asked me to just give me a number

**My answer** : 4 billion
**Interviewer** : Why ?
**Me**: Because i like the number "4 billion"
**Interviewer**: Busted into laughs

And then after he moved on to other questions

**What is interviewer trying to conclude from my answer and what could be the reason he asked ?**

**Edit**: The interview was for QA Engineer position

Comment: How in depth you can get on ambiguous questions.

Comment: Those are "Microsoft questions". See this [WTF post](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/riddle-me-an-interview.aspx) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/478039/349708).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this kind of questions is a way to assess the ability of logic and to think out-of-box of the interviewee.

Here is another example: [the market for light bulbs in Australia](http://www.acethecase.com/site/1438552/page/760234), though it is for another industry, and thus of higher standard of expectation of the answer.

Bonus (not 100% related to the question): another typical question for a QA position is [how to test an elevator](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/61139), and do not confuse it with [the elevator test](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/can-your-team-pass-the-elevator-test.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is what Joel Spolsky refers to as a "back of the envelope question".

"A good back-of-the-envelope question allows you to have a conversation with the candidate that helps you form an opinion about whether they are smart"

A better strategy would probably have been to try and figure out an even vaguely reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [fermi question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem), intended to check the estimation skills.